# extending a drive using gparted software failed

Tags: gparted

im unable to extend my drive using gparted. i added 700GB to the virtual machine and then booted the Ubuntu iso using "try now" option and then run GPARTED see pictures below, what am i doing wrong? why the expand is disabled?

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/486J8.png)

[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7avih.png)

Answer (score 3):

/dev/sda5 lives inside the extended partition /dev/sda2.

Extend /dev/sda2 first, then /dev/sda5.

Comment: Hi, im unable to resize/move /dev/sda2 the option is grayed out...